# What will be the best way to remove duplicates in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## List with duplicate items

`fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'apple', 'pears', 'mango', 'cherry', 'apple']`

## Solution 1 using set()

`uniques = set(fruits)
print(uniques)`

## Solution 2 using function

`def removeDuplicate(input): 
  secondList = []

  for item in fruits: 
    if item not in secondList: 
      secondList.append(item)
  return secondList 
newList = removeDuplicate(fruits) 
print(sorted(newList))`

Both removed all the duplicate and provide new list

## Solution 1 gave me result as a set

## Solution 2 gave me result as a list

Comment: If you need it as a list, say `uniques = list(set(fruits))`. But it's definitely better (faster and more readable/reliable) than creating a custom function

Comment: @sacul 's answer is the best solution. Definitely much better than defining another function. sacul : will you like to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple function, should work. Similar to what user:sacul posted.

```
def remove_dup(my_list):
    return list(set(my_list))

fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'apple', 'pears', 'mango', 'cherry', 'apple']
remove_dup(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

## You Can Also Use List Comprehension

```
prog_langs = ['C', 'C++', 'C#', 'Java', 'Python', 'C', 'PHP', 'C', 'Java']

no_dup_prog_list = [i for i in set(prog_langs)]
print(no_dup_prog_list)
```